# How to Enable Android Opera mini browser off-road mode?

Tags: google-play-store, browser, opera-mini, opera-browser, browser-add-ons

Recently I found that, enabling off-road mode in Opera mini browser is a great way to hide my browsing data from ISP. So I installed the version 24.0.2254. But I couldn't find the option in enable the off-road mode. Seems like this option is available in old versions but not in latest ones. Is off-road mode is obsolete now or is there any alternative options available?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Opera Mini, Offroad mode is automatically enabled. If you are concerned about your browsing data (Privacy), you can use a VPN.